# leaflet geojsos, updating makers with Ajax, how to remove all markers before re adding?

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet

Im using GeoJSON with leaflet to insert markers onto a map, I then have a Ajax request periodically update the icons every 60 seconds with their latest state (they go red or green if the location is up or down)

However it's been noted that the page looked like it had a memory leak, on further investigations we can see that additional markers are added on each refresh, so with 100 markers on the map after an hour we have 6000 markers. Can anyone help me on making the existing markers update based on the new data or remove and re add them?

current code below

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = L.map('map').setView([54.0,-3.4], 7);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox/dark-v10',
        accessToken: 'pk.*****'
    }).addTo(map);


    $(function() {
        function update_maps() {
            // Update the pins in the amaps
            $.get('/monitoring/data/status_map_geo_data/gb/', function(geo_data) {
                        L.geoJSON(geo_data, {
                            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                                var zindex = feature.properties.z_index && feature.properties.z_index !== "null";
                                return L.marker(latlng, {
                                    zIndexOffset: zindex  ? 1000 : 0,
                                    icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon(
                                                {
                                                    icon: feature.properties.icon, 
                                                    markerColor: feature.properties.color, 
                                                    prefix: 'fa', 
                                                    iconColor: 'white',
                                                }
                                            )
                                        }
                                    );
                            },
                            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                                var layer_text = '<h3><a href="/sites/site/'+feature.properties.site_id+'">'+feature.properties.popupContent+'</a></h3>'
                                layer.bindPopup(layer_text)
                            }
                        }).addTo(map);  
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // load icons on start
            update_maps()
        });
        // refresh page
        setInterval(function() {
            update_maps()
        }, 60 * 1000);

        

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple solution, `L.geoJSON` returns a group with the markers, this group can be cleared with `.clearLayers()`.

So change your code to:

```
var geoJsonGroup = null;
function update_maps() {
            // Update the pins in the amaps
            $.get('/monitoring/data/status_map_geo_data/gb/', function(geo_data) {
                        if(geoJsonGroup){
                           geoJsonGroup.clearLayers();
                        }
                        geoJsonGroup = L.geoJSON(geo_data, {
                            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                                var zindex = feature.properties.z_index && feature.properties.z_index !== "null";
                                return L.marker(latlng, {
                                    zIndexOffset: zindex  ? 1000 : 0,
                                    icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon(
                                                {
                                                    icon: feature.properties.icon, 
                                                    markerColor: feature.properties.color, 
                                                    prefix: 'fa', 
                                                    iconColor: 'white',
                                                }
                                            )
                                        }
                                    );
                            },
                            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                                var layer_text = '<h3><a href="/sites/site/'+feature.properties.site_id+'">'+feature.properties.popupContent+'</a></h3>'
                                layer.bindPopup(layer_text)
                            }
                        }).addTo(map);  
            });
        }
```

**Alternatives (From @gyhbs) *"Many roads lead to Rome"*:**

1. Call `geoJsonGroup.removeFrom(map)` instead of `geoJsonGroup.clearLayers();`
2. Put the `L.geoJSON` outside and then call `addData` instead of creating a new group everytime:

```
var geoJsonGroup = L.geoJSON(null, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var zindex = feature.properties.z_index && feature.properties.z_index !== "null";
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            zIndexOffset: zindex ? 1000 : 0,
            icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
                icon: feature.properties.icon,
                markerColor: feature.properties.color,
                prefix: 'fa',
                iconColor: 'white',
            })
        });
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        var layer_text = '<h3><a href="/sites/site/' + feature.properties.site_id + '">' + feature.properties.popupContent + '</a></h3>'
        layer.bindPopup(layer_text)
    }
}).addTo(map);

function update_maps() {
    // Update the pins in the amaps
    $.get('/monitoring/data/status_map_geo_data/gb/', function(geo_data) {
        if (geoJsonGroup) {
            geoJsonGroup.clearLayers();
        }
        geoJsonGroup.addData(geo_data)
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not simply removing it from the map, instead of leaving an empty and no longer referenced Layer Group? Or another way of achieving this could be to `addData` instead of creating a new Group everytime.

Comment: I updated the answer, but I don't know which is the best solution, there are many ways to do this

Comment: Indeed there are always plenty ways of doing it ;-)